# Algorithm to indicate existence of a perfect matching in a graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory, matching

I am trying to design an algorithm that indicates whethere a graph has a **perfect matching** or not.
Is there any known or unknown algorithm to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can try finding the maximum matching using the Blossom algorithm and then verify if your maximum matching is a perfect matching by checking if your maximum matching is "touching" all the elements in your set of vertices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm